# How to assign key to map function Javascript

Tags: reactjs, map-function

How can i assign this index to key attribute on this return of map function.

`map((eachItem,index) => eachItem._id)`

Comment: more details and code please

Answer (score 1):

Assigning index as a key to component is not advised, but if you still want to use it then you can do it like this:

```
items.map((eachItem,index) => 
    <p key={index}> {eachItem._id} </p>
```

Here is a wonderful article by Mosh about keys: [React List and Keys](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists/#:%7E:text=React%20recommends%20that%20you%20do,to%20some%20unstable%20component%20behaviour.)